# Asynchronous computation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently I've been toying with **TensorFlow** and I mentioned that the framework is not able to use all my available computational resources. In [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) tutorial they mention that

> Naively employing asynchronous updates of model parameters leads to sub-optimal training performance because an individual model replica might be trained on a stale copy of the model parameters. Conversely, employing fully synchronous updates will be as slow as the slowest model replica.

Although they mention it in both in the tutorial and in a [whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) I did not really find a way to do the asynchronous parallel computation on a local machine. Is it even possible? Or is it part of the distributed to-be-released version of TensorFlow. If it is, then how?

Comment: I just wish I was smart enough to even understand this question. Best of luck.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Asynchronous gradient descent is supported in the open-source release of TensorFlow, without even modifying your graph. The easiest way to do it is to execute multiple **concurrent steps** in parallel:

```py
loss = ...

# Any of the optimizer classes can be used here.
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

def train_function():
  # TODO: Better termination condition, e.g. using a `max_steps` counter.
  while True:
    sess.run(train_op)

# Create multiple threads to run `train_function()` in parallel
train_threads = []
for _ in range(NUM_CONCURRENT_STEPS):
  train_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=train_function))

# Start the threads, and block on their completion.
for t in train_threads:
  t.start()
for t in train_threads:
  t.join()
```

This example sets up `NUM_CONCURRENT_STEPS` calls to `sess.run(train_op)`. Since there is no coordination between these threads, they proceed asynchronously.

It's actually more challenging to achieve *synchronous* parallel training (at present), because this requires additional coordination to ensure that all replicas read the same version of the parameters, and that all of their updates become visible at the same time. The [multi-GPU example for CIFAR-10 training](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) performs synchronous updates by making multiple copies of the "tower" in the training graph with shared parameters, and explicitly averaging the gradients across the towers before applying the update.

---

**N.B.** The code in this answer places all computation on the same device, which will not be optimal if you have multiple GPUs in your machine. If you want to use all of your GPUs, follow the example of the [multi-GPU CIFAR-10 model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), and create multiple "towers" with their operations pinned to each GPU. The code would look roughly as follows:

```py
train_ops = []

for i in range(NUM_GPUS):
  with tf.device("/gpu:%d" % i):
    # Define a tower on GPU `i`.
    loss = ...

    train_ops.append(tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss))

def train_function(train_op):
  # TODO: Better termination condition, e.g. using a `max_steps` counter.
  while True:
    sess.run(train_op)


# Create multiple threads to run `train_function()` in parallel
train_threads = []
for train_op in train_ops:
  train_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=train_function, args=(train_op,))


# Start the threads, and block on their completion.
for t in train_threads:
  t.start()
for t in train_threads:
  t.join()
```

Note that you might find it convenient to use a ["variable scope"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) to facilitate variable sharing between the towers.

Comment: This is so simple that it really did not come to my mind :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any reason you used python threading module instead of multi-processing here ?

Comment: Yes, because a `tf.Session` object isn't transparently shareable between multiple Python processes. The `sess.run()` function releases the GIL, so multiple steps will run concurrently from different Python threads.

Comment: Does this solution do all of the computation on a single device? I think many readers may be interested in doing asynchronous gradient descent with each thread running on a different GPU.

Comment: I updated it to provide some suggestions for multiple devices. Thanks for the suggestion, Ian!

Comment: If there are multiple threads using the same graph, while doing forward prop or while doing backprop, don't threads overwrite the forward prop values / intermediate gradient calculations ? How does session.run() in each thread work ? Do they each have it's own scratch space for doing gradient calculations and then they update the same variables ?

Comment: That's right: each invocation to `session.run()` uses independent scratch space. Only the values written to `tf.Variable` objects (and some other stateful objects, such as queues) are shared.

Comment: Thanks. But does the scratch space also contain copy of `tf.Variable` or is it always shared. So it's possible that one threads update of variables affect the other threads gradient calculations ?

Comment: I guess your previous comment clarifies it ! So if we want the gradients to be correct then it's better to have explicit towers in the graph. Thanks !

Comment: @mrry Do you have to use `use_locking=True` for `GradientDescentOptimizer` in your examples?

Comment: @mrry The links to the multi-GPU CIFAR 10 training is broken. Is the repository deleted?