# Multithreading - How to use CPU as much as possible?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, tensorflow, profiling

I'm currently implementing Tensorflow custom op(for custom data fetcher) using C++ in order to speed up my Tensorflow model. Since my Tensorflow model doesn't use GPU a lot, I believe I can achieve maximal performance using multiple worker threads concurrently.

The problem is, even though I have enough workers, my program doesn't utilize all CPU. In my development machine, (4 physical core) it uses about 90% of user time, 4% of sys time with 4 worker threads and `tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=6)`options.

With more worker threads and `inter_op_parallelism_threads` options, I get much worse model running performance than previous configuration. Since I don't good at prpfiling I don't know where is the bottleneck of my code.

Is there any rule of thumbs to maximize CPU usage and/or good tools to find performance bottleneck/mutex lock for single process(not system-wide) in Linux?

EDIT: My code runs python, but (almost) every executions are in C++ code. Some of them are not mine(Tensorflow and and Eigen), and I've made a shared library that can be dynamically loaded in Python and it is being called by Tensorflow kernel. Tensorflow owns their thread pool and my dynamic library code also owns thread pool, and my code is [thread safe](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f64dd7d20289e76bb70f35f98b9a28cf91e18393/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L76). I also create threads to call `sess.run()` concurrently in order to call them. Like Python can call multiple HTTP requests concurrently, `sess.run()` release GIL. My object is call `sess.run()` as much as possible to increase "real" performance, and any python-related profiler wasn't succesful.

Comment: I think you contradict yourself a little. First you mention that _"my program utilize all cpu"_ and then you say _"is there any rule of thumbs to maximise CPU usage"_. So do you want to increase the CPU load or decrease it?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall It was typo. Fixed.

Comment: You should start with using a profiler to find the bottleneck. For what it's worth the CPU may be waiting for the data to be fetched from memory/disk most of the time.

Comment: *With more worker threads...  I get much worse model running performance* -- Assuming you're using CPython, multiple threads will hurt CPU-bound performance because only 1 thread works at a time in Python, but you end up with a lot of overhead because of how threads acquire and release the Global Interpreter Lock. To improve CPU-bound work, you need multiple processes. Also consider that your bottleneck may not actually be the CPU.

Comment: @sytech AFAIK tensorflow's sess.run() release GIL, so, it is typical to call sess.run() functions concurrently. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34420169

Comment: @ByoungchanLee Tensorflow utilizes multiple worker ***processes***. This allows you to utilize multiple CPU cores and divide up work between processes. Each process still has its own GIL.  Within a process, you can have multiple *threads* -- Using more threads per process will not necessarily make your processing faster. You have to carefully schedule tasks such that you're not trying up execution threads for unbounded periods of time while waiting for I/O and other events to occur. You generally get best performance with 1 **process** per CPU core.

Comment: @sytech Tensorflow don't create(fork or something) any prcesses. They manages their own thread pool and [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__ThreadPool__Module.html)'s one, even though I don't create any thread explicitly, and their thread creation codes are all written in C++.

Comment: @ByoungchanLee  That's true, you're right. However, they're still just pthreads. You generally get the best performance by having `inter_op_parallelism_threads` (number of ops that can execute in parallel) and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` (number of parallel threads within an op) both equal to the number of cores you have. This should be the default behavior, if Tensorflow correctly detects the number of cores.

Answer (score 3):

1) More threads does not mean more speed. If you have 4 cores, you cannot go any faster than 4 times 1 core.

2) What you should do is [*tune your code for maximum performance in single-thread execution (with compiler optimization turned off)*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262), and after you have done that, turn on the compiler's optimizer and make the code multi-threaded, with no more threads than you have cores.

P.S. It is a common misconception that performance tuning can only be done on compiler-optimized code. [*This explains*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/329124/2429) why it's not so.