# Run multiple tensorflow experiments in the same program

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to run multiple experiments from the same python program. I'm thinking of running them in parallel. Here are two ideas:
1) 1st idea is to use python multiprocessing for each experiment, but it's a bit cumbersome to communicate to a different process (only first class citizen Python data structures can be passed easily)
2) Another idea would be to somehow run multiple `sess.run` asynchronously, but since `sess.run` is a blocking operation I can't launch others. By launching multiple experiments in the same `sess.run` I'll end up waiting for the longest experiment.
Can Tensorflow figure out when it has enough resources to run the next async experiment in parallel?
Any ideas how to achieve the second idea. Or is it just easier to use the first idea.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419645/asynchronous-computation-in-tensorflow however it doesn't mention that tensorflow is aware when it has enough resources to start the new thread, as to process them in an efficient way

Comment: maybe multiprocessing is better since it properly frees memory when the process is over. I've had issues in the past where Python wouldn't garbage collect things