# how to get the 'mathematical' gradient of output w.r.t neural network parameters and compute cosine between two such gradients

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a neural network `out = f(s)`, where `s` is a batch of input with shape`[None, dim_s]`, while out is a scaler, `f` is simply a MLP. With `tf.gradient(out, tf.trainable_variables())` I can get gradient of `out` w.r.t neural network parameters of `f`, which is a list of gradient.

Now, I have two different batch of `s`: `s1` and `s2`, then we can get two different the above gradients `G1` and `G2`.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_1=np.random.normal(0,1, [2, 3])
batch_2=np.random.normal(0,1, [2, 3])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))

out = tf.layers.dense(x, 2, tf.tanh,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(
                                  stddev=np.sqrt(1 / 100)))
predictions = tf.layers.dense(out, 1, tf.tanh,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(
                                  stddev=np.sqrt(1 / 100)))

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
gradient_step = opt.compute_gradients(predictions, tf.trainable_variables())

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
gradients_1 = sess.run(gradient_step, feed_dict={x: batch_1})
gradients_2 = sess.run(gradient_step, feed_dict={x: batch_2})
```

If it is possible to compute cosine between `G1` and `G2`? Do I need to flatten both gradients first? Do `G1` and `G2` are the usual gradient in math?

Answer (score 1):

**Re mathematical:** As far as I can guess what you mean by "mathematical", the gradients in tensorflow are "mathematical". For example, if your `f` is `f(x) = x^3`, you run it on `x=5`, and get `tf.gradients` of it, you will get `75 = 3*5^2`.

**Re cosine:** Yes, you can do this, but it requires a bit of deeper understanding of TensorFlow gradient computation. To compute gradients, you need to remember the values of the forward pass. In the example above, to compute `75` you need to remember `5`. In general, this is potentially all the tensors computed by all operations in `f`. By default, TensorFlow will remember these values only until the gradients are computed. Then, the values are discarded.

If you want to work with two sets of gradients, the easiest way is to instantiate your model twice. This is usually referred to as having two "towers". These towers will share the variables and their structure will be identical, but each will have its own set of operations (nodes in the tensorflow graph). Then, you feed `s1` as the input into the first tower and `s2` as the input into the second tower (in the same session.run() call).

If you have millions of operations and instantiating two towers is too expensive, you can create a tensorflow [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3d1452c6a4a37c9f5d6f1da77d335cc43f9b7fc8/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py#L80) (this experimental API).

Another potentially easier option is to use the recently released eager [execution](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/10/eager-execution-imperative-define-by.html) where operations are executed immediately (there is no graph and no `session.run()`) and you have easy control of gradient computations using GradientTapes. You can find examples of its usage in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3d1452c6a4a37c9f5d6f1da77d335cc43f9b7fc8/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop_test.py#L317). Eager Execution is in a pre-alpha state right now and only available in tf-nightly builds. See "Nightly Builds" in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow).

**In Response to comment 3:**
As far as I can tell, your example clearly shows that gradients are summed over the batch. The variables in the dense layer have shapes `3x1` and `1x1`:

```
print tf.trainable_variables()
    [<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

The first gradient (for the `3x1` variable) is:

```
print gradients_1[0][0]
    array([[-0.098351  ],
           [-0.6422075 ],
           [ 0.09750339]], dtype=float32)
```

So, there is one scalar for each scalar variable, even though `batch_1` has 2 scalars for each scalar variable.

I already wrote how you can use "towers" to be able to work with two gradients from different inputs. Here is an example based on your code snippet. I assume by "cosine" you mean "cosine similarity"

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
predictions1 = tf.layers.dense(x1, 1, tf.tanh,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(
                                   stddev=np.sqrt(1 / 100)),
                               reuse=None)
predictions2 = tf.layers.dense(x2, 1, tf.tanh,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(
                                   stddev=np.sqrt(1 / 100)),
                               reuse=True)

weights = tf.trainable_variables()[0]   # the 3x1 weight variable
g1 = tf.reshape(tf.gradients(predictions1, weights), [-1])   # 3x1 gradient tensor
g2 = tf.reshape(tf.gradients(predictions2, weights), [-1])   # 3x1 gradient tensor

cos_similarity = 1 - tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.nn.l2_normalize(g1, 0),
                                               tf.nn.l2_normalize(g2, 0),
                                               dim=0)

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print sess.run([g1, g2, cos_similarity], feed_dict={
    x1: [[1,2,3], [2,4,6]],
    x2: [[1,2,3], [2,4,7]]
    })

# prints
# [array([ 3.,  6.,  9. ], dtype=float32),
#  array([ 3.,  6.,  10.], dtype=float32),
#  0.99876773]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I want to explain a bit more about the mathematical means, in your example, suppose `f` is a parametrical function, say `f(x)=w*x+b` or `f(x)=MLP(x)`,  where `w` and `b` and `f(x)` is a scaler, `x` is a batch input, are both trainable variables, then `tf.gradient(f, tf.trainable_variables())` will get a list of gradient, with each element is the gradient of `f` w.r.t EACH trainable variable in `f(x)`, like `w` and `b`. I DO NOT understand how does this gradient means, it is not a form which supposed to be such as a vector.

Comment: The reason output of `tf.gradient` is not a vector as you expect is because all gradients are summed within a batch. See `aggregation_method` in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients. Also, the first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324767/tensorflow-how-to-get-gradients-per-instance-in-a-batch.

Comment: Hi @iga, it seems that the gradient won't be summed over a batch, see [here](https://gist.github.com/Erichliu00/23dc0e214982b66a59edd6acf1fe4629). Given such two gradient, how can the cosine between them be computed?

Comment: Hi @iga, thanks. I understand it now finally.  When having multiple variables, the resulting gradient is a list of gradient, if one want to get a cosine similarity, one need to consider a single variable, such as in the example you provided above.

Comment: Hi @iga, indeed the confusion also comes out from the dimension of variables, suppose `tf.trainable_variables()` contains variables with shape like `3x2`, then gradient w.r.t it is also `3x2`, given two such gradients, shall we flatten them first?

Comment: The shape is up to you. You can do the same calculation on any shape. Also, if this answer answers your question, it is a good practice to mark the answer as "accepted".