# Asynchronous computation in TensorFlow using Estimator API

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing

What would be the answer for this question [Asynchronous computation in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419645/asynchronous-computation-in-tensorflow) when we want to perform asynchronous training, using multiple (CPU) threads, but on top of a model implemented using the Estimator API?

For instance on [a model like this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/cifar10_main.py)?